# Remove default addons section in TaskInfoPanel

Tags: twilio

I am trying to remove the default "Addons" section from TaskInfoPanel (see example here https://twilio-cms-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/flexwithnewcomponent.width-800.png)

In the docs it's pretty well explained how to add or remove custom components by key but I don't find any way to remove this default section. I tried as follows without any luck:

```
flex.TaskInfoPanel.Content.remove('addons');
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this same problem was to "replace" the TaskInfoPanel content

```
flex.TaskInfoPanel.Content.replace(<CustomTaskListContainer key="demo-component" />, options);
```

Making this replacement, my taskinfopanel delete all related info and take place my custom content designed as CustomTaskListContainer